# Connect negative isDirty with a disabled class

Tags: ember.js, refactoring

Is there a way to refactor the following code to make it cleaner or is a `{{#if}}` the cleanest way to solve this?

```
{{#if isDirty}}
  <button {{action 'save' this}} class="btn">Save</button>
  <button {{action 'discard' this}} class="btn">Discard</button>
{{else}}
  <button class="btn disabled">Save</button>
  <button class="btn disabled">Discard</button>
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to solve this with CSS:

```
<button {{bindAttr class=":btn content.isDirty:enabled:disabled"}}>Save</button>
```

You could use CSS to prevent the clicks when disabled (if your target browsers support it). Or just let the clicks go through and only call commit/rollback if content.isDirty.

Another option would be to bind the disabled property of the button:

```
<button {{bindAttr disabled="content.isDirty:enabled:disabled"}}>Save</button>
```

Comment: Beautiful! I prefer the CSS too. A very clean solution. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't need the `enabled` class you can leave it out
`<button {{bindAttr class=":btn content.isDirty::disabled"}}>Save</button>`